# Java - making a variable specific to a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So, I'm fairly new to Java and programming in general and haven't really found a solution to my problem.

I'm writing a program which contains a for loop within a for loop, and in the first loop I am using the variable `i` and I wanted to use the same letter, but technically a different variable for the for loop within it.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=numofdoors.length; i+=modifier){
    for(int i = 0; i <= (numofdoors.length - numofdoors.length%modifier)/modifier; i+=1){
    // ....
    }
}
```

omitting details on what the program actually is doing, I was just wondering if there was a way to make the 1int i1 work only in each for loop, so I can use i as my variable in any for loop I use. If anyone can tell me how to do this and if it is even possible I'd appreciate it. If some other method is better practice I will also appreciate it.

Comment: Don't try to use the same variable name, take `j` instead for the inner loop… Even if it was working, you and every other reader of your code would get confused easily!

Comment: No, you can't. Your inner for-loop has to use different variable name, e.g. `j`

Comment: You can if you extract the inner for loop to a different method. Note that it's pretty surprising (and probably a bug) to never use the outer `i` variable anywhere.

Comment: Much appreciated! I figured it might actually be a good idea to just keep track of more variables but at the same time wondered if there was another solution.

Comment: If something like that would be possible, how would you distinguish between the two `i` variables in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use different variables for loops with intersecting scopes (outer scope includes inner scope). Just use a different letter:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= someBorder; i += someValue) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= someThing; j++) {
    // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use other variable to avoid the confusion 
e.g.

`for(int i = 0; i<=numofdoors.length; i+=modifier){
    for(int j = 0; j <= (numofdoors.length - numofdoors.length%modifier)/modifier; j+=1){
    // ....
    }
}`

As Outer `i` has the scope in the inner loop as well so it is not allowing you to get compile.

Its about scope of variables.

and its more benefits to avoid the confusion to read and write program. Always remember program should be readable and anyone should understand it easily .

Comment: It's not just about avoiding confusion. It's about making the code compile.